# Override fetch of Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When I create a new collection, fetch a response, and override the parse, I see the array of models logged inside the collection, but I can't access it after the fetch returns. Is it because I'm not specifying something in the `fetch` method properly?

```
class MyCollection extends Backbone.Collection

      model: MyModel

      fetch: () ->

        $.ajax
          type: 'GET'
          url: '/customurl'
          success: (data) =>
            @parse data

      parse: (resp) ->

        if !resp
          return []

        things = []

        # parse that shit and things.push new MyModel()

        console.log 'things: ' + JSON.stringify things # this logs correctly

        things

window.myCollection = new MyCollection()
window.myCollection.fetch()

# wait some time, see it logged inside collection parse method...
console.log JSON.stringify window.myCollection # logs as []
```

Comment: not duplicate - the error lies with however that 'fetch' method is used. if i use the default fetch with a custom parse, it works.

Answer (score 0):

try passing `async: false` as an option to the fetch method:

`window.myCollection.fetch({async: false})`

you may not be seeing anything in the `console.log` because it is being called *before* the results have returned. `parse` is only called *after* the results have returned. **you're probably better off doing any custom logic in a function `foo()`,** and then calling that function with the updated collection whenever fetch happens:

`window.myCollection.on("reset", foo)`

You can define the function like: `foo(updatedCollection)` and do whatever with the collection. This approach follows a bit more closely to the event-driven emphasis of Backbone.

also, as a side note, as long as you [specify `url: '/customurl'` as a property](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url) in your collection, you can get rid of your override of the `fetch` method. backbone will use the `GET` by default and it will send successful results to `parse` by default.

just a suggestion. hope the above works.

Comment: Sorry, the note: 'wait some time, see it logged inside collection' gets called WAY after the collection has returned -- had to remove a lot of code to show the basic collection. Also, the 'url' attribute changes (interesting API to use), so that's why it's not set as a default param.

Comment: Ah I see. Two things: One, I updated my response above. And 2, you could try redefining the collection's `url` with `myCollection.url = someVar`, in the case where the API url varies.

Comment: I like the idea of the on ('reset', foo)! I guess I should elaborate: parse DOES get called, and I see [thing1,thing2] in the logs inside of parse. If I override parse ONLY, it seems to work. It's when I override fetch that it breaks. I will try the last comment you suggested as well!